# CSS validation parse error on calculation of font-size

Tags: css, parsing

I have this code in my css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  html {
    font-size: calc(16px + (20 - 16) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1000 - 320)));
  }
}
```

Why do I get this parse error on CSS validation? See image below.

[CSS Parse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRvuQ.png)

Comment: but does it work? it seems yes

Comment: `/ (1000 - 320)` => `/680` and `20 -16` can be written as `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `calc` the right hand side of `/` must be a number. See this [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Syntax) for the rules. So `(1000 - 320)` is an expression thus it cannot be there, it has to be a number like **680**

`font-size: calc(16px + (20 - 16) * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));`